# Tensorflow Optimizers - multiple loss values passed to minimize()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, gradient-descent

My first time using Tensorflow on the MNIST dataset, I had a really simple bug where I forgot to take mean of my error values before passing it to the optimizer.

In other words, instead of

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=y, labels=y_))
```

I accidentally used

```
loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=y, labels=y_)
```

Not taking the mean or sum of the error values threw no errors when training the network, however. This led me thinking: **Is there actually a case when someone would need to pass in multiple loss values into an optimizer? What was happening when I passed in a Tensor not of size [1] into minimize()?**

Answer (score 4):

They are being added up. This is side-product of TensorFlow using Reverse Mode AD to differentiate, which requires loss to be a scalar

Comment: So if you pass a tensor, you basically minimizing the sum of all values in the tensor?

Comment: ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;yes